# Microsoft Word for Mac page number

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, page-numbers

I'm using word for Mac and trying to insert page numbering, I keep getting { PAGE } instead of numbers, when I insert in both header or footer, Kindly assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Press `Opt`+`F9` *(or `Fn`+`Opt`+`F9`)* to toggle display of Field Codes

From my webpage: [The Function Keys and Keyboard Shortcuts That Manipulate Fields](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#Function)

`Shift`+`F9` is also a toggle shortcut, but it is a temporary one.
`Opt`+`F9` changes your system preferences. If the document is opening with { PAGE } displayed, you need the system preferences changed.

Comment: +1 This must surely work for the OP.

Comment: It worked for me, thank you so much